# Ognl exprssion is not working

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, struts, ognl

```
<s:set var="p" value="licenseeProfileBean" />
<s:set var="pp" value="individualBean.resAddress" />

<s:property value="((#p).(#pp)).personName" />
```

i am getting no value of 'personName'. Here licenseeProfileBean is parent bean, individualBean bean is a property of licenseeProfileBean  and resAddress is property of individualBean.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.